# How to run DROOLS (Drl) in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, drools

is it not possible to run Drools in tomcat?
Can i run rules(Drl file) thorugh Tomcat or Jetty web server except JBOSS>?
Please share any example?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Drools is just a Java framework. You can run it inside a webapp without any problem. Try and you'll see.